# Dr Smith meets an alien

Tags: episode-identification, lost-in-space, lost-in-space-1965

I have a faint memory of a Lost In Space episode where Dr Smith is getting things he wants from an alien device.

He gets (I think) a drink of wine and then he asks for a beautiful girl but this hideous creature appears and terrifies him.

I've searched for "Dr Smith and an alien" and also "Dr Smith and a monster" but I keep getting led down rabbit holes of trivia.

Question is:- Which episode please?
(I genuinely haven't seen this in over 50 years so my memory could be at fault)

Comment: https://tvdatabase.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_in_Space:_Space_Destructors?

Comment: I don't think that's the one, iirc there was more of a Morlock look about the creature

Answer (score 14, accepted):

["Wish Upon a Star"](https://lostinspace.fandom.com/wiki/Wish_upon_a_Star)

> Although Smith remains ensconced in his now fabulously appointed camp, he graciously shares the helmet with the Robinsons. Very soon, though, it becomes apparent that having the means of making your fondest wishes come true has very serious negative effects on the various members of the crew. Even after John's stern words bring his family back to their senses, Smith continues to indulge his every whim. When he wishes for a servant, however, he has gone to far. A strange mummy-like being appears out of a locker in the aft of the ruined spaceship and moves toward him. Smith fears for his life and runs back to the Jupiter 2, the creature in pursuit. He arrives just as the Robinsons have discovered that everything they wished into existence has now fallen to pieces. When the creature arrives, John demands an explanation, but it is clear that the visitor is only seeking the helmet which Smith has hidden away. Eventually, John is able to bring about its return to the ruined ship and the creature retires with it back into the locker from which it emerged. When Will tries to follow, he finds only an empty, cobweb filled space, with no sign of the creature or the helmet. Will wonders why the alien took the device back and John tells him it was greed and selfishness—Smith asked for too much.

### Episode Review with a still of the monster

### Still of the servant

[image: Image of the alien servant]

Found with a search for `"lost in space" "dr. smith" "alien machine"`

Comment: "fabulously appointed camp", in..DEED!!